# jQuery donut plugin: Arrow doesn't show on print

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, user-interface

I was trying to use this jQuery plugin to show a percentaje donut on a page:

> http://larentis.eu/donuts/

When I add the code to the page, it works perfectly and you can see everything is ok:

[image]

But when I go to the print preview I don't see the arrow pointing the percentage value on the donut:

[image]

After a little research I saw the css used for this plugin and the arrow has the class **.donut-arrow** and it has the following styles associated:

```
/* line 38, ../sass/donuts.scss */
.donut .donut-arrow {
  height: 1em;
  width: .1em;
  margin-left: -.05em;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 100%;
  -moz-transform-origin: 50% 100%;
  -ms-transform-origin: 50% 100%;
  -o-transform-origin: 50% 100%;
  transform-origin: 50% 100%;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s;
  transition: all 0.5s;
}
/* line 49, ../sass/donuts.scss */
.donut .donut-arrow, .donut .donut-arrow:before {
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  background: #333;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
/* line 57, ../sass/donuts.scss */
.donut .donut-arrow:before {
  content: '';
  height: .2em;
  width: .2em;
  bottom: -.1em;
  margin-left: -.1em;
  -webkit-border-radius: 100%;
  -moz-border-radius: 100%;
  -ms-borderradius: 100%;
  -o-border-radius: 100%;
  border-radius: 100%;
}
```

What css styling should I add to see this arrow while printing the page?

**Any Idea? Thank You very much!**

**Update:**  I added the jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/KRcMg/

Comment: Create a jsfiddle.net and we will try to help you fix it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The arrow itself is a `div` with a background-color:

```
.donut .donut-arrow, .donut .donut-arrow:before {
    background: #333;
}
```

Backgrounds won't display when printing. As such, your best bet will probably be to try and recreate the arrow with the same markup, using borders instead of a background colour.

Something like:

```
.donut-arrow {
    width: 0;
    border: .05em solid #000;
}
```

You'll want to size the borders using `em`'s, as that will let you maintain the different sizes of the arrows according to the parent class.

Comment: Yes, with your answer I can show the arrow borders and to see the little ball on the base of the arrow I had to add: .donut-arrow:before {
   border:.05em solid #000;
}

Comment: By the way, what styles should I add to add color to all the arrow instead the borders only? Thanks for your help!

Comment: Well, that's the heart of the issue: background-color is the right tool for styling the elements, but that won't show up in print. Personally, I think I'd add a separate print style to just add a 1px black border (assuming that printing is an edge case, so differences don't much matter).